String de bytes. ¿Cómo leerlo?
Estoy utilizando conjuntos de datos netCDF que contienen cambios futuros en el uso del suelo (descargados de:

https://data.pnnl.gov/group/nodes/dataset/13192).

Tengo un archivo para cada 5 años desde 2015 hasta 2100. He creado un script en python para leerlos y guardarlos como archivos .tif:
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import rasterio
from rasterio.transform import from_origin
from netCDF4 import Dataset
import os
import glob

#Definimos una funcion para abrir la carpeta que contiene los archivos nc
def abrir_nc_carpeta():
   

    #Definimos la ruta de la carpeta
    files = os.listdir('E:/Modelos/LANDUSE change/Rotacion mapas/nc')
    #Creamos una carpeta en la que se guardaran los raster
    os.mkdir('Raster')
    #os.mkdir('ASCII')  Esto solo si queremos también los ascii
    #Metemos en un bucle la funcion que saca los PFT y los convierte en raster
    for archivo_nc in files:
        
        leer_nc(archivo_nc)
        print(archivo_nc)

#Definimos una funcion que lee los nc y PFT y los convierte en raster
def leer_nc(archivo_nc):
    
    # Llamar a cada archivo nc
    ds = Dataset(archivo_nc , 'r+')
    print(ds)

    # Extraer los datos de latitud y longitud
    arr_lat = ds['latitude'][:]
    arr_lon = ds['longitude'][:]

    # Iterar sobre los valores de PFT
    for PFT in range(33):
        # Obtener los datos de PFT correspondientes
        arr_data = ds['PFT{}'.format(PFT)][:]
          
        # Crear un DataFrame con latitud y longitud como índices y los datos de arr_data
        df = pd.DataFrame(arr_data, index=arr_lon, columns=arr_lat)

        # Convertir el DataFrame a un array numpy
        array_data = df.values

        # Definir la información de georreferenciación
        transform = from_origin(arr_lon.min(), arr_lat.max(), arr_lon[1] - arr_lon[0], arr_lat[0] - arr_lat[1])
        
        #Cambiar valores nan
        array_data_no_nan = np.nan_to_num(array_data, nan=-9999)
        
        #Flip porque el mapa sale en espejo
        fliped = np.flip(array_data_no_nan, 0)

        # Guardar el array como un archivo GeoTIFF
        with rasterio.open('Raster/{}; PFT{}.tif'.format(archivo_nc, PFT), 'w', driver='GTiff', height=fliped.shape[0], width=fliped.shape[1], count=1, dtype=fliped.dtype, crs='EPSG:4326', transform=transform) as dst:
            dst.write(fliped, 1)
            

abrir_nc_carpeta()



El problema es que algunos archivos (algunos años) se leen como binarios y otros no. Por lo tanto, los archivos que se leen como binarios me dan este error:
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: b'GCAM_Demeter_LU_ssp1_rcp26_gfdl_2015.nc'
He intentado usar un código de decodificación:

def abrir_nc_carpeta():

     # Definimos la ruta de la carpeta
    folder_path = 'E:/Modelos/LANDUSE change/Rotacion mapas/nc'
    
    # Usamos os.listdir() para obtener una lista de nombres de archivos en el directorio
    files_bytes = os.listdir(folder_path)
    
    # Convertimos los nombres de archivo de bytes a cadenas de texto Unicode
    files = [file_name.decode('utf-8') for file_name in files_bytes]
    
    # Creamos una carpeta en la que se guardarán los raster
    os.mkdir('Raster')
    
    # Iteramos sobre los nombres de archivo
    for file_name in files:
        # Llamamos a la función leer_nc con el nombre de archivo directamente
        leer_nc(file_name)
        print(file_name)


Pero obtengo este error:
AttributeError: 'str' el objeto no tiene el atributo 'decode'
¿Qué puedo hacer para poder leer todos los archivos?

Pues verifica que el tipo sea bytes primero. Si lo es lo conviertes y sino no haces nada

os.listdir devuelve objetos path-like, esto puede ser bytes o str, para obtener el path en str se puede usar la función os.fsdecode.
En tu caso sería:
files = [os.fsdecode(file_name) for file_name in files_bytes]

Más información:
https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html#os.listdir
https://docs.python.org/3/glossary.html#term-path-like-object
https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html#os.fsdecode
